# Finding an unknown value between 2 data points

Tags: javascript, math

Basically I have a set of data like

```
var data = [
    {idx: 0, value: 10},
    {idx: 20, value: 15},
    {idx: 45, value: 24},
    {idx: 100, value: 55},
];
```

I'm looking for a way to interpolate/estimate what the value of an unmapped point (such as an idx of 32) would be. I'm a little out of my element here, and would love to learn more about how to tackle this problem, so some direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd say that's a more general math problem, not a specific programming problem. This might be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26137003/2521214 if you have always just 4 points then single interpolation cubic suffice just change t parameter to idx and cover with it whole curve. if you have many points then use piecewise interpolation as in the link ...