# How to sort colors in two dimensions?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, colors, calculus

I am currently working on a hobby project to automatically solve a puzzle from the popular mobile game *I Love Hue*. The game is available [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zutgames.ilovehue&hl=en).

Basically, the whole premise of the game is that you're given a bunch of colored rectangular blocks organized in a grid. You can swap most of the blocks except for a few fixed blocks, which are marked by black dots. The object of the game is to swap the blocks around so you get a two-dimensional spectrum of color. The colors are sorted such that the color of each block is approximately the average of the colors around it. (Sorry, I don't know any color theory but there's probably a word for what I'm looking for.) Here's what a typical puzzle looks like:

[image: img]

I have already been able to take screenshots through adb, extract the RGB matrix from the blocks and mark which blocks are "fixed". I'm having trouble with the actual algorithmic part of this problem.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Converting the RGB to HSV and sorting the colors by hue in a one-dimensional list. This gives me a spectrum, but I do not know how to convert this result into two dimensions.
2. Leaving the colors in RGB and attempting to work with a singular color. There's probably some multivariable calculus I could do here, but the difficulty lies in the fact that some colors share one or more of their RGB values. It would be necessary to consider all three colors.
3. Using Euclidean distance to find the distance between each pair of colors. I understand that the final goal is to have this distance to be the smallest among adjacent colors, but the two-dimensional grid is making this more difficult.
4. Using Euclidean distance, I have developed a metric for how ideal a certain grid is by looking at the Euclidean distance of the colors of adjacent blocks. However, I cannot find an efficient algorithm that can figure out the swaps necessary to get to an ideal state.

Comment: ok I havent played the game but from the front cover of the game it looks like there are 4 possible orientations of the colors that would result in a smooth finish... just wondering if the game accepts all 4 combinations. Or is there always some fixed blocks to ensure only one solution exists?

Comment: @TheoWalton there are always some fixed blocks to ensure only one solution exists.

Comment: The image you referenced looks like a blend of varying hue and saturation. The color saturation increases from the image center radially to the image borders. The hue varies with the angle around the image center. This way you have 2 dimensions in polar coordinates. The black-dotted color patches now declare the control points for an interpolation over an irregular grid. However, without having seen any other sample images from that game, it is still open, whether the color gradients always follow the polar coordinates I mentioned above.

Comment: It certainly looks like they are varying hue and saturation to get the colours. So HSV is indeed the right starting point.

Comment: Have you got an example of the dataset from the image above? I'm fascinated by this. I think that sorting the colors by distance on each axis in two different matrixes is the way to go here, and finding the average distance from each endpoint on each axes.

Comment: @GarrettGu added **edit2** with my C++ solution attempt (looks like it is working)  and link to win32 demo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you have more `solved` images you could create RGB graphs plot**

so plot the **3D** graph where `x,y` is pixel position and `z` is inspected color channel (R,G or B). From it you can determine some properties of the gradients. If the plot is a plane than all you need is just the normal (taken from 3 known cells). If it is curved surface depending on how many inflex points it got you can determine how big polynomial was used for it. From all this you can start solving this.

**I would start with something simple** (assuming not too big gaps or fancy polynomials):

Handle each color channel separately. I would use just the static tiles and interpolate the grid colors only from them. Something similar to:

- [Interpolating 3D Coordinates between known missing time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963357/2521214)

Without seeing the **R,G,B** graphs I can not estimate which kind of interpolation you need. If the graphs are linear use bi-linear or linear interpolation. If not use higher degree polynomials.

So fill in any grid cells that you can (has neighbors with known color). After this find the closest movable tile to computed color (if cell has all 3 channels interpolated) and place them (and set as static).

Now just repeat the process until all the cells are computed.

**[Edit1 Dec 14 2017] some additional notes and stuff**

Was curious and got some time today so I gave it a shot. First I create the game in C++/VCL which took your image as input (cropped and resized). Then I sorted the tiles manually and plot the graphs:

[image: RGB plots]

The White dots means tile is placed correctly (match the interpolated color). The colored circles around the dots are the interpolated colors (for visual comparison you need to zoom to see them).

As you can see the **R,G,B 3D** plots looks linear so (bi)linear interpolation should be enough.

If I tried just linear interpolation for rows only the solver solves the puzzle immediately. However When I coded the same for columns (more unknown cells between known ones) the solver started to make few incorrect placings (invalidating the whole stuff hence the wrong white dots).

[image: column solver]

I Also tried **HSL** but after a while I throw it away due to hitting a wall because **Hue** can cross the `0` and `360` degree at any point which is not distinguishable from cases that did not cross. For that it would need some heuristics or cross correlation from neighboring solved areas and that would be too much coding for my taste. Without it the results where even worse then using **RGB**.

So now I am thinking about either using bilinear interpolation or solve the short distance interpolations first and only then solve the rest ...

**[Edit2 Dec 14 2017] bilinear interpolation**

Looks like bilinear **RGB** interpolation solves all the issues. So if your board is enclosed with fixed cells it should work. If not you need to solve the board iteratively and then use the newly solved cells as new bound for the unsolved areas. Also I realized I got **RGB** reversed so I also repaired that :).

Here the **C++/VCL** source for the game (It is not optimized at all):

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TForm1 *Form1;
bool _update=false;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const _ILoveHue_state_fixed   =255<<24;
const _ILoveHue_state_unsolved=  0<<24;
const _ILoveHue_state_solved  =  1<<24;
const _ILoveHue_render_board=0;
const _ILoveHue_render_graph=1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int rgbdist(DWORD c0,DWORD c1)  // AABBGGRR
    {
    int r0,g0,b0,r1,g1,b1;
    r0=( c0     &255); r1=( c1     &255);
    g0=((c0>> 8)&255); g1=((c1>> 8)&255);
    b0=((c0>>16)&255); b1=((c1>>16)&255);
    r0-=r1; g0-=g1; b0-=b1;
    return (r0*r0)+(g0*g0)+(b0*b0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ILoveHue
    {
public:
    // variables
    bool _redraw;               // redraw needed?
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;     // screen buffer
    int sxs,sys,mxs,mys,gxs,gys;// screen,map,grid cell resolution
    DWORD **map,**imap;         // map[y][x] actual and interpolated
    int mx,my,mx0,my0;          // mouse position state actual and last
    TShiftState sh,sh0;         // mouse buttons and spec keys state actual and last
    int render_mode;
    // class constructors and destructors
    ILoveHue()  { bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap; bmp_resize(1,1); map=NULL; imap=NULL; mxs=0; mys=0; mx=-1; my=-1; mx0=-1; my0=-1; gxs=1; gys=1; render_mode=_ILoveHue_render_board; }
    ~ILoveHue() { map_free(); if (bmp) delete bmp; }
    ILoveHue(ILoveHue& a)   { *this=a; }
    ILoveHue* operator = (const ILoveHue *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //ILoveHue* operator = (const ILoveHue &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    // game/Window API and stuff
    void map_free()                             // relese map
        {
        if ( map) { if ( map[0]) delete[]  map[0]; delete[]  map; }  map=NULL; mxs=0; mys=0;
        if (imap) { if (imap[0]) delete[] imap[0]; delete[] imap; } imap=NULL;
        }
    void map_resize(int x,int y)                // resize/allocate map
        {
        _redraw=true;
        if ((x==mxs)&&(y==mys)) return; map_free();
         map=new DWORD*[y]; if ( map==NULL) return;  map[0]=new DWORD[x*y]; if ( map[0]==NULL) return;
        imap=new DWORD*[y]; if (imap==NULL) return; imap[0]=new DWORD[x*y]; if (imap[0]==NULL) return;
        mxs=x; mys=y; for (x=mxs,y=1;y<mys;y++,x+=mxs) { map[y]=map[0]+x; imap[y]=imap[0]+x; }
        if (mxs) gxs=sxs/mxs; else gxs=1;
        if (mys) gys=sys/mys; else gys=1;
        }
    void bmp_resize(int x=-1,int y=-1)          // resize bmp
        {
        _redraw=true;
        if ((x>=0)&&(y>=0)) bmp->SetSize(x,y);
        bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
        bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
        sxs=bmp->Width;
        sys=bmp->Height;
        if (mxs) gxs=sxs/mxs; else gxs=1;
        if (mys) gys=sys/mys; else gys=1;
        }
    void bmp_load(AnsiString file)              // init game from image (map must be resized already)
        {
        _redraw=true;
        // load file
        bmp->LoadFromFile(file);
        bmp_resize();
        // convert to map
        int x,y;
        DWORD *p,c;
        for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
         for (p=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[(y*gys)+(gys>>1)],x=0;x<mxs;x++)
            {
            c=p[(x*gxs)+(gxs>>1)+4]&0x00FFFFFF;         // near mid point (0<<24 is unsolved state)
            c=((c>>16)&0x000000FF)                      // RGB -> BGR (file has reverse RGB order than bmp)
             |((c<<16)&0x00FF0000)
             |( c     &0x0000FF00);
            map[y][x]=c;
            c=p[(x*gxs)+(gxs>>1)]&0x00FFFFFF;           // mid point
            if ((((c)|(c>>8)|(c>>16))&255)<64)          // ~max(R,G,B)<32
             map[y][x]|=_ILoveHue_state_fixed;
            }
        }
    void mouse(int x,int y,TShiftState s)       // handle mouse
        {
        _redraw=true;
        mx=x/gxs;
        my=y/gys;
        sh0=sh; sh=s;
        bool q0=sh0.Contains(ssLeft);
        bool q1=sh .Contains(ssLeft);
        if ((!q0)&&( q1)){ mx0=mx; my0=my; }    // mouse left button down
        if (( q0)&&(!q1))                       // mouse left button up (swap)
            {
            // swap if valid coordinates
            if ((mx0>=0)&&(mx0<mxs)&&(my0>=0)&&(my0<mys)) if (DWORD(map[my0][mx0]&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_fixed)
             if ((mx >=0)&&(mx <mxs)&&(my >=0)&&(my <mys)) if (DWORD(map[my ][mx ]&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_fixed)
                {
                DWORD c=map[my0][mx0]; map[my0][mx0]=map[my][mx]; map[my][mx]=c;    // swap cells
                map[my0][mx0]&=0x00FFFFFF; map[my0][mx0]|=_ILoveHue_state_unsolved; // set them as unsolved
                map[my ][mx ]&=0x00FFFFFF; map[my ][mx ]|=_ILoveHue_state_unsolved;
                map_solve(false);                                                   // check for solved state
                }
            // clear selection
            mx0=-1; my0=-1;
            }
        }
    void draw()                                 // render game
        {
        _redraw=false;
        int x,y,z,x0,x1,x2,y0,y1,y2,r;
        DWORD c;
        if (render_mode==_ILoveHue_render_board)
            {
            for (y0=0,y1=gys,y2=gys>>1,y=0;y<mys;y++,y0+=gys,y1+=gys,y2+=gys)
             for (x0=0,x1=gxs,x2=gxs>>1,x=0;x<mxs;x++,x0+=gxs,x1+=gxs,x2+=gxs)
                {
                c=map[y][x];
                bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(c&0x00FFFFFF);
                if ((x==mx )&&(y==my )) bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clYellow;
                if ((x==mx0)&&(y==my0)) bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clGreen;
                bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=TColor(c&0x00FFFFFF);
                bmp->Canvas->Rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1);

                if (DWORD(c&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_fixed)
                    {
                    r=10;
                    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=imap[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF;
                    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsClear;
                    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x2-r,y2-r,x2+r,y2+r);
                    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Style=bsSolid;
                    }

                if (DWORD(c&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_unsolved)
                    {
                    if (DWORD(c&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_fixed ) c=clBlack;
                    if (DWORD(c&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_solved) c=clWhite;
                    r=4;
                    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=c;
                    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=c;
                    bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(x2-r,y2-r,x2+r,y2+r);
                    }
                }
            }
        if (render_mode==_ILoveHue_render_graph)
            {
            bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlack;
            bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
            bmp->Canvas->Rectangle(0,0,sxs,sys);
            r=13; x0=15; y0=sys-15;
            int c=r*double(256.0*cos(55.0*M_PI/180.0));
            int s=r*double(256.0*sin(55.0*M_PI/180.0));
            bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clRed;
            for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
             for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
                {
                z=(map[y][x])&255;
                x1=x0+(x*r)+((y*c)>>8);
                y1=y0      -((y*s)>>8);
                bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1);
                bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y1-z);
                } x0=x1+5;
            bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clGreen;
            for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
             for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
                {
                z=(map[y][x]>>8)&255;
                x1=x0+(x*r)+((y*c)>>8);
                y1=y0      -((y*s)>>8);
                bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1);
                bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y1-z);
                } x0=x1+5;
            bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlue;
            for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
             for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
                {
                z=(map[y][x]>>16)&255;
                x1=x0+(x*r)+((y*c)>>8);
                y1=y0      -((y*s)>>8);
                bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x1,y1);
                bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x1,y1-z);
                }

            }
        }
    // Solver
    void map_solve(bool _solve) // check for solved state and try to solve if _solve is true
        {
        _redraw=true;
        const int _thr=10;  // color comparison threshold
        int x,y,x0,x1,y0,y1,xx,yy;
        int r0,g0,b0,r,g,b;
        int r1,g1,b1;
        int r2,g2,b2;
        int r3,g3,b3;
        DWORD c;

        // compute interpolated colors to imap (wanted solution)
        for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
         for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
          if (DWORD(map[y][x]&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_fixed)
            {
            for (x0=-1,xx=x;xx>= 0;xx--) if (DWORD(map[y][xx]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_fixed){ x0=xx; break; }
            for (x1=-1,xx=x;xx<mxs;xx++) if (DWORD(map[y][xx]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_fixed){ x1=xx; break; }
            for (y0=-1,yy=y;yy>= 0;yy--) if (DWORD(map[yy][x]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_fixed){ y0=yy; break; }
            for (y1=-1,yy=y;yy<mys;yy++) if (DWORD(map[yy][x]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_fixed){ y1=yy; break; }
            c=0;
            if (int(x0|x1|y0|y1)>=0)
                {
                // bilinear interpolation
                c=map[y0][x0]; r0=c&255; g0=(c>>8)&255; b0=(c>>16)&255;
                c=map[y0][x1]; r1=c&255; g1=(c>>8)&255; b1=(c>>16)&255;
                c=map[y1][x0]; r2=c&255; g2=(c>>8)&255; b2=(c>>16)&255;
                c=map[y1][x1]; r3=c&255; g3=(c>>8)&255; b3=(c>>16)&255;
                r0=r0+(r1-r0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                g0=g0+(g1-g0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                b0=b0+(b1-b0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                r1=r2+(r3-r2)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                g1=g2+(g3-g2)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                b1=b2+(b3-b2)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0);
                r =r0+(r1-r0)*(y-y0)/(y1-y0);
                g =g0+(g1-g0)*(y-y0)/(y1-y0);
                b =b0+(b1-b0)*(y-y0)/(y1-y0);
                c=(r)+(g<<8)+(b<<16);
                }
            imap[y][x]=c;
            }

        // compute solved state
        for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
         for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
          if (DWORD(map[y][x]&0xFF000000)!=_ILoveHue_state_fixed)
            {
            map[y][x]&=0x00FFFFFF;
            if (rgbdist(map[y][x],imap[y][x])<_thr) map[y][x]|=_ILoveHue_state_solved;
             else                                   map[y][x]|=_ILoveHue_state_unsolved;
            }

        // solver/checker
        if (_solve)
            {
            // process all unsolved cells
            for (x=0;x<mxs;x++)
             for (y=0;y<mys;y++)
              if (DWORD(map[y][x]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_unsolved)
               // find match in unsolved cells
               for (xx=0;xx<mxs;xx++)
                for (yy=0;yy<mys;yy++)
                 if (DWORD(map[yy][xx]&0xFF000000)==_ILoveHue_state_unsolved)
                  if (rgbdist(map[yy][xx],imap[y][x])<_thr)
                    {
                    // swap if found
                    c=map[yy][xx];
                    map[yy][xx]=map[y][x];
                    map[y][x]=(c&0x00FFFFFF)|_ILoveHue_state_solved;
                    }
            }
        }
    } gam;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    gam.map_resize(7,9);
    gam.bmp_load("map.bmp");
    gam.map_solve(false);
    _update=true;
    ClientWidth=gam.sxs;
    ClientHeight=gam.sys;
    _update=false;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    gam.render_mode=_ILoveHue_render_board;
    gam.draw();
    gam.bmp->SaveToFile("map.bmp");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender){ gam.draw(); Canvas->Draw(0,0,gam.bmp); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender){ if (_update) return; gam.bmp_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight); }
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender){ if (gam._redraw) FormPaint(Sender); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y){ gam.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y){ gam.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y){ gam.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
    {
    if (Key=='S') gam.map_solve(true);                      // try to solve
    if (Key=='M') { gam.render_mode^=1; gam._redraw=true; } // swap render modes
    if (Key==115) gam.bmp->SaveToFile("screenshot.bmp");    // [F4] screenshot
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is a single Form App in BDS2006 with single 40ms Timer on it. So just add the events ... You can ignore the VCL rendering and window stuff. The important thing is the class and the `solve()` function in it. It is used for both correct placing check and for solving (depending on the `_solve` bool). This is the input image **map.bmp**

[image: map.bmp]

I did not code appropriate save/load state functions instead I chose to use the bitmap itself directly (waste of space but almost no code effort).

The map itself is **2D** 32bit `DWORD` array with form of `SSBBGGRR hex` where `SS` is the flag of the cell (fixed/solved/unsolved).

Here compiled demo with the source code

- [Win32 demo](https://ulozto.net/!Hg88x6Scf2XG/ilovehue-zip)

Read the `readme.txt` for more info. Here result after solving (pressing [S]):

[image: solved state]

As you can (not) see the circles vanish as the bilinearly interpolated color matches more closely your input.

Program is expecting grid of size 7x9 the resolution of image is not important. The color is sampled from mid point of cell (black dot) and slightly to the right (the tile color)

To make this efficient you can make 2 things:

1. **add/use list containing unsolved cells**

   instead of itearting over whole map iterate only through list of unsolved cells.
2. **convert `T(N^2)` searches to `T((N^2)/2)` by triangle search**

   This is still `O(N^2)` however but the constant time is smaller.
3. **use 3D RGB LUT table**

   for large grids you can create 32K entries **3D LUT** table to find the searched matching cell in `O(1)`. Simply convert RGB to 15 bit color and use

   ```
   DWORD LUT[32][32][32];
   ```

   where `LUT[r][g][b]=row+(column<<16);` Tis way you will know where each color is placed. All the unused colors set to `0xFFFFFFFF`. Here an example of using this technique for similar purpose:

   - [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214)

   Look for `recolor[32][32][32]` in the code... Of coarse 15bit color may be not enough for this purpose so may be you would need more bits like 18bit resulting in 256K entries which is still manageable.

   Creating this **LUT** will take `O(N)` time but using and maintaining it is only `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea if this would work or not. I've just wrote it for fun and could not apply a real test on it. It would be appreciated if you kindly give it a try and comment about it.

```
        struct pixel
        {
            public int R;
            public int G;
            public int B;
            public bool Fixed;
            public pixel(int r, int g, int b, bool _fixed)
            {
                this.R = r; this.G = g; this.B = b; this.Fixed = _fixed;
            }
            public int DistanceSQ(pixel px)
            {
                int r = this.R - px.R;
                int g = this.G - px.G;
                int b = this.B - px.B;
                return r * r + g * g + b * b;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", this.R, this.G, this.B, this.Fixed);
            }
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return this.R.GetHashCode() ^ this.G.GetHashCode() ^ this.B.GetHashCode();
            }
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                pixel px = (pixel)obj;
                return this.R == px.R && this.G == px.G && this.B == px.B;
            }
        }
        static void sort(pixel[,] img)
        {            
            List<pixel> lst = new List<pixel>();
            foreach (pixel px in img)
                if (!px.Fixed)
                    lst.Add(px);

            int rows = img.GetLength(0);
            int cols = img.GetLength(1);
            while (lst.Count > 0)
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
                    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                        if (!img[row, col].Fixed)
                        {
                            pixel[] neighbors = getFixedNeighbors(img, row, col, rows, cols).ToArray();
                            int min = int.MaxValue;
                            pixel nearest = new pixel();
                            foreach (pixel n in lst)
                            {
                                int dist = neighbors.Select((a) => a.DistanceSQ(n)).Sum();
                                if (dist < min)
                                {
                                    min = dist;
                                    nearest = n;
                                }
                            }
                            nearest.Fixed = true;
                            img[row, col] = nearest;
                            lst.Remove(nearest);
                            if (lst.Count == 0)
                                return;
                        }
        }
        private static IEnumerable<pixel> getFixedNeighbors(pixel[,] img, int row, int col, int rows, int cols)
        {
            for (int r = Math.Max(0, row - 1); r < Math.Min(row + 2, rows); r++)
                for (int c = Math.Max(0, col - 1); c < Math.Min(col + 2, cols); c++)
                    if (img[r, c].Fixed)
                        yield return img[r, c];

        }



        //test
        {
            bool b0 = false; bool b1 = true;//for easy editing 
            {
                pixel[,] img = new pixel[3, 4];
                img[0, 0] = new pixel(0, 0, 0, b1); img[1, 0] = new pixel(0, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 0] = new pixel(0, 2, 0, b1);
                img[0, 1] = new pixel(1, 0, 0, b0); img[1, 1] = new pixel(1, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 1] = new pixel(1, 2, 0, b0);
                img[0, 2] = new pixel(2, 0, 0, b0); img[1, 2] = new pixel(2, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 2] = new pixel(2, 2, 0, b0);
                img[0, 3] = new pixel(3, 0, 0, b1); img[1, 3] = new pixel(3, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 3] = new pixel(3, 2, 0, b1);
                sort(img);
            }
            {
                pixel[,] img = new pixel[3, 4];
                img[0, 0] = new pixel(0, 0, 0, b1); img[1, 0] = new pixel(0, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 0] = new pixel(0, 2, 0, b1);
                img[0, 1] = new pixel(2, 0, 0, b0); img[1, 2] = new pixel(2, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 2] = new pixel(2, 2, 0, b0);
                img[0, 2] = new pixel(1, 0, 0, b0); img[1, 1] = new pixel(1, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 1] = new pixel(1, 2, 0, b0);
                img[0, 3] = new pixel(3, 0, 0, b1); img[1, 3] = new pixel(3, 1, 0, b0); img[2, 3] = new pixel(3, 2, 0, b1);
                sort(img);
            }
        }
```

Code is simple. It keeps the not-rated ones in a list and remove each when the location is found for it. For deciding which color should be choosen for a location, color that has the minimum sum of square distance is choosen. Sqrt is not required since we only need it for comparison.

"sort" is the main function that changes the locations of the not fixed pixels. The input for this function is a row-col array of pixels. "sort" function make changes on this array.

Comment: add some words on how it works. Pure un-commented code is hard to grasp for anyone other then its author even if it looks simple....

Comment: @Spektre I have added some explanations about it. I hope its sufficient. The code explains itself better. I don't think we need to deal with interpolation for this problem; but I'm not exactly sure about it. Thanks.

Comment: that is slightly better but I feel to make this usable for others You should at least add what the main variables are and means and how the input and output of the puzzle is stored (format).

Comment: I'm bad in explaining things. I hope its better now.

Comment: I added **edit2** with my C++ solution attempt (looks like it is working)  and link to win32 demo to my answer. Take a look at the `solve()` function. As you can see the interpolation is not that much code. On the other hand creating combination or rotations of swaps (like you are proposing) could get hideous and probably much slower...

Comment: Thats great, well done. I just don't see how my proposal is slower and hideous. I prefer measuring before saying something is slower or not. I'm not sure about my code's validness, and dont have time to test it now; I'll try it when I find some.