# Sort colors in two dimensions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, colors

For the needs of a web project, I would like to generate a color picker from a list of defined colors. Here is what I've done:

[image: unsorted color picker]

As you can see, the colors aren't sorted. I found a lot of algorithms to sort colors, but not in 2D. The result that I would like to have is something like this:

[image: sorted color picker]

Have you any idea of what I could do? Thanks.

If you wonder, I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760628/how-to-sort-colors-in-two-dimensions) but the problematic isn't the same: I don't already know the final position of 50% of the colors.

Here is a tentative to sort by red on the x-axis and by green on the y-axis:

[image: red green sorted color picker]

Comment: Sort after red horizontally and green vertically

Comment: where do you have the last picture from? does the source contains some more information?

Comment: I've got this picture from Gimp.

Comment: I've tried what you proposed to do (I edited the first post). The result isn't incredible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help [Danny_ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5708620/danny-ds) and [Harsh Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054638/harsh-gupta).
I was trying to make a color picker that was "smouth" on both X and Y axis. I've tried a dozen of different algorithms and it just doesn't look fine. So now, I just sort on only one axis and then I sort each lines. The result look very good:

[image: sorted color picker]

Here is the sources:

```js
'use strict';

let colors = [{
  "name": "Black",
  "hexa": "000000"
 },
 {
  "name": "Sable",
  "hexa": "202020"
 },
 {
  "name": "Grey/Gray",
  "hexa": "808080"
 },
 {
  "name": "Argent",
  "hexa": "E5E5E5"
 },
 {
  "name": "Silver",
  "hexa": "C0C0C0"
 },
 {
  "name": "White",
  "hexa": "FFFFFF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Snow",
  "hexa": "FFFAFA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Gainsboro",
  "hexa": "DCDCDC"
 },
 {
  "name": "Linen",
  "hexa": "FAF0E6"
 },
 {
  "name": "Wheat",
  "hexa": "F5DEB3"
 },
 {
  "name": "Antiquewhite",
  "hexa": "FAEBD7"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkgray",
  "hexa": "A9A9A9"
 },
 {
  "name": "Dimgray",
  "hexa": "696969"
 },
 {
  "name": "Floralwhite",
  "hexa": "FFFAF0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Ghostwhite",
  "hexa": "F8F8FF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightgray",
  "hexa": "D3D3D3"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightslategray",
  "hexa": "778899"
 },
 {
  "name": "Red",
  "hexa": "FF0100"
 },
 {
  "name": "Brown",
  "hexa": "A52A2A"
 },
 {
  "name": "Maroon",
  "hexa": "800000"
 },
 {
  "name": "Gules",
  "hexa": "DD0100"
 },
 {
  "name": "Crimson",
  "hexa": "DC143C"
 },
 {
  "name": "Indianred",
  "hexa": "CD5C5C"
 },
 {
  "name": "Orangered",
  "hexa": "FF4501"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mistyrose",
  "hexa": "FFE4E1"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkred",
  "hexa": "8B0000"
 },
 {
  "name": "Firebrick",
  "hexa": "B22222"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightsalmon",
  "hexa": "FFA07A"
 },
 {
  "name": "Orange",
  "hexa": "FFA502"
 },
 {
  "name": "Gold",
  "hexa": "FFD702"
 },
 {
  "name": "Or",
  "hexa": "FFE403"
 },
 {
  "name": "Chocolate",
  "hexa": "D2691E"
 },
 {
  "name": "Coral",
  "hexa": "FF7F50"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightcoral",
  "hexa": "F08080"
 },
 {
  "name": "Moccasin",
  "hexa": "FFE4B5"
 },
 {
  "name": "Navajowhite",
  "hexa": "FFDEAD"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkorange",
  "hexa": "FF8C01"
 },
 {
  "name": "Yellow",
  "hexa": "FFFF03"
 },
 {
  "name": "Tan",
  "hexa": "D2B48C"
 },
 {
  "name": "Bisque",
  "hexa": "FFE4C4"
 },
 {
  "name": "Ivory",
  "hexa": "FFFFF0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Beige",
  "hexa": "F5F5DC"
 },
 {
  "name": "Cornsilk",
  "hexa": "FFF8DC"
 },
 {
  "name": "Goldenrod",
  "hexa": "DAA520"
 },
 {
  "name": "Khaki",
  "hexa": "F0E68C"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lemonchiffon",
  "hexa": "FFFACD"
 },
 {
  "name": "Blanchedalmond",
  "hexa": "FFEBCD"
 },
 {
  "name": "Burlywood",
  "hexa": "DEB887"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkgoldenrod",
  "hexa": "B8860B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkkhaki",
  "hexa": "BDB76B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Yellowgreen",
  "hexa": "9ACD32"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightgoldenrodyellow",
  "hexa": "FAFAD2"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightyellow",
  "hexa": "FFFFE0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Oldlace",
  "hexa": "FDF5E6"
 },
 {
  "name": "Palegoldenrod",
  "hexa": "EEE8AA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Papayawhip",
  "hexa": "FFEFD5"
 },
 {
  "name": "Green",
  "hexa": "018001"
 },
 {
  "name": "Vert",
  "hexa": "019301"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lime",
  "hexa": "04FF03"
 },
 {
  "name": "LightGreen",
  "hexa": "90EE90"
 },
 {
  "name": "Olive",
  "hexa": "808001"
 },
 {
  "name": "Chartreuse",
  "hexa": "7FFF03"
 },
 {
  "name": "Honeydew",
  "hexa": "F0FFF0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Springgreen",
  "hexa": "06FF7F"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumseagreen",
  "hexa": "3CB371"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lawngreen",
  "hexa": "7CFC03"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkgreen",
  "hexa": "016400"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkolivegreen",
  "hexa": "556B2F"
 },
 {
  "name": "Seagreen",
  "hexa": "2E8B57"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkseagreen",
  "hexa": "8FBC8F"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkslategray",
  "hexa": "2F4F4F"
 },
 {
  "name": "Forestgreen",
  "hexa": "228B22"
 },
 {
  "name": "Greenyellow",
  "hexa": "ADFF2F"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightseagreen",
  "hexa": "20B2AA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumaquamarine",
  "hexa": "66CDAA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumspringgreen",
  "hexa": "07FA9A"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mintcream",
  "hexa": "F5FFFA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Palegreen",
  "hexa": "98FB98"
 },
 {
  "name": "Azure/Blue",
  "hexa": "0800FF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Teal",
  "hexa": "038080"
 },
 {
  "name": "Cyan/Aqua",
  "hexa": "0CFFFF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Turquoise",
  "hexa": "40E0D0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightblue",
  "hexa": "ADD8E6"
 },
 {
  "name": "Navy",
  "hexa": "020080"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightcyan",
  "hexa": "E0FFFF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Midnightblue",
  "hexa": "191970"
 },
 {
  "name": "Slateblue",
  "hexa": "6A5ACD"
 },
 {
  "name": "Cadetblue",
  "hexa": "5F9EA0"
 },
 {
  "name": "Aliceblue",
  "hexa": "F0F8FF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Aquamarine",
  "hexa": "7FFFD4"
 },
 {
  "name": "Cornflowerblue",
  "hexa": "6495ED"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkblue",
  "hexa": "02008B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkcyan",
  "hexa": "038B8B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkslateblue",
  "hexa": "483D8B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkturquoise",
  "hexa": "08CED1"
 },
 {
  "name": "Deepskyblue",
  "hexa": "0ABFFF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Dodgerblue",
  "hexa": "1E90FF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightskyblue",
  "hexa": "87CEFA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightsteelblue",
  "hexa": "B0C4DE"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumslateblue",
  "hexa": "7B68EE"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumturquoise",
  "hexa": "48D1CC"
 },
 {
  "name": "Paleturquoise",
  "hexa": "AFEEEE"
 },
 {
  "name": "Indigo",
  "hexa": "4B0082"
 },
 {
  "name": "Violet",
  "hexa": "EE82EE"
 },
 {
  "name": "Purple",
  "hexa": "800080"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lavender",
  "hexa": "E6E6FA"
 },
 {
  "name": "Plum",
  "hexa": "DDA0DD"
 },
 {
  "name": "Mediumpurple",
  "hexa": "9370DB"
 },
 {
  "name": "Blueviolet",
  "hexa": "8A2BE2"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkmagenta",
  "hexa": "8B008B"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkviolet",
  "hexa": "9400D3"
 },
 {
  "name": "Pink",
  "hexa": "FFC0CB"
 },
 {
  "name": "Fuchsia/Magenta",
  "hexa": "FF00FF"
 },
 {
  "name": "Purpure",
  "hexa": "B31F85"
 },
 {
  "name": "Orchid",
  "hexa": "DA70D6"
 },
 {
  "name": "Hotpink",
  "hexa": "FF69B4"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darkorchid",
  "hexa": "9932CC"
 },
 {
  "name": "Darksalmon",
  "hexa": "E9967A"
 },
 {
  "name": "Deeppink",
  "hexa": "FF1493"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lavenderblush",
  "hexa": "FFF0F5"
 },
 {
  "name": "Lightpink",
  "hexa": "FFB6C1"
 }
];

function hexToRgbColor(hexColor) {
 return [
  parseInt(hexColor.substr(0, 2), 16),
  parseInt(hexColor.substr(2, 2), 16),
  parseInt(hexColor.substr(4, 2), 16)
 ];
}

function rgbToHsvColor(rgbColor) {

 const r = rgbColor[0];
 const g = rgbColor[1];
 const b = rgbColor[2];

 let rabs, gabs, babs, rr, gg, bb, h, s, v, diff, diffc, percentRoundFn;
 rabs = r / 255;
 gabs = g / 255;
 babs = b / 255;
 v = Math.max(rabs, gabs, babs);
 diff = v - Math.min(rabs, gabs, babs);
 diffc = c => (v - c) / 6 / diff + 1 / 2;
 percentRoundFn = num => Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
 if (diff == 0) {
  h = s = 0;
 } else {
  s = diff / v;
  rr = diffc(rabs);
  gg = diffc(gabs);
  bb = diffc(babs);

  if (rabs === v) {
   h = bb - gg;
  } else if (gabs === v) {
   h = (1 / 3) + rr - bb;
  } else if (babs === v) {
   h = (2 / 3) + gg - rr;
  }
  if (h < 0) {
   h += 1;
  } else if (h > 1) {
   h -= 1;
  }
 }
 return [
  Math.round(h * 360),
  percentRoundFn(s * 100),
  percentRoundFn(v * 100)
 ];
}

function rgbToLuminance(rgbColor) {
  return Math.sqrt(.299*rgbColor[0]*rgbColor[0] + .587*rgbColor[1]*rgbColor[1] + .114*rgbColor[2]*rgbColor[2]);
}

function sortArray(array, compareValueGetter) {

 array.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
  const value1 = compareValueGetter(elem1);
  const value2 = compareValueGetter(elem2);
  return value1 > value2 ? 1 : (value1 < value2 ? -1 : 0);
 });
}

const nbOfColumns = 11;
const palette = document.getElementById('palette');

for (const color of colors) {
 color.rgb = hexToRgbColor(color.hexa);
 color.hsv = rgbToHsvColor(color.rgb, false);
 color.luminance = rgbToLuminance(color.rgb);
}

sortArray(colors, color => color.hsv[0]);

let sortedColors = [];
let line;

while (colors.length > 0) {

 line = colors.splice(0, nbOfColumns);
 sortArray(line, color => color.luminance)
 sortedColors = sortedColors.concat(line);
}

let tile;
for (const color of sortedColors) {
 tile = document.createElement('div');
 tile.style.backgroundColor = '#'+color.hexa;
 palette.appendChild(tile);
}
```

```css
#palette{
 width: 220px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#palette>div{
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

#palette div:hover::after{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
 left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="palette"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The second image is not simply a matrix with colors sorted in some way. It is actually a section of a 3-D Color Model viewed from an angle. A Color Model is a visualization showing color spectrum in multidimensions. Tools like GIMP shows you a section of such spectrum.

For example, consider a cube with origin vertex (0, 0, 0). For RGB, each axis is nothing but a range of respective color values ranging from 0 to 255. Along X axis, we have R values from 0 to 255, along Y axis we have G values from 0 to 255 and along z-axis we have B values from 0 to 255. At origin (0, 0, 0), we have black color. At the opposite end, we have vertex (255, 255, 255) which is white. You can have any color value by changing a value along an axis.

For more details, you may like to read: https://programmingdesignsystems.com/color/color-models-and-color-spaces/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the colors from RGB to HSL and then sort on Hue and Saturation (x / y for example).

To order the colors as in your second image you could think of the Hue being on a colorwheel and convert to a x/y position that fits in your square or rectangle.

Alternatively you could sort on Red / Green (x/y) as already mentioned in the comments (the extra image you show is not sorted by red/green).