# How to smoothly encode 2-dimensional location by colors

Tags: python, colors, color-scheme, color-theory

In a few webpages ([link1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/97267/two-dimensional-divergent-color-scheme), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760628/how-to-sort-colors-in-two-dimensions)) I have seen people filling 2D planes by colors:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

However, these examples are given without source code. How can I generate plot like this in Python? Specifically, if I have array of `x` and `y` values, how can I write a function `color = f(x, y)`, so that `scatter(x, y, color)` can generate plot like this?

So far I have tried the following method:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base_x_color = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
base_y_color = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])

x = np.random.rand(100000)
y = np.random.rand(100000)
color = x[:,None] * base_x_color[None,:] + y[:,None] * base_y_color[None,:]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, c=color)
plt.show()
```

However, the generated image (shown below) always have one black corner. I would like to set all four corners as non-black colors, and smoothly transit between them.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to implement [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

resolution = 500 

x = np.linspace(0, 1, resolution)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, resolution)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

color_1 = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])  # Red
color_2 = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0])  # Green
color_3 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0])  # Blue
color_4 = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0])  # Yellow

color = np.zeros((resolution, resolution, 3))
color += (1 - X)[:, :, None] * (1 - Y)[:, :, None] * color_1[None, None, :]
color += X[:, :, None] * (1 - Y)[:, :, None] * color_2[None, None, :]
color += (1 - X)[:, :, None] * Y[:, :, None] * color_3[None, None, :]
color += X[:, :, None] * Y[:, :, None] * color_4[None, None, :]

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(color, origin='lower', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1])
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: colors]

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, it seems the `np.random.rand` produced values near zero, so yes you can use `np.random.uniform` to control low and high

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base_x_color = np.array([0, 1.0, 0.0])
base_y_color = np.array([1.0, 0, 0.0])

x = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=0.8, size=(100000,))
y = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=0.8, size=(100000,))

color = x[:,None] * base_x_color[None,:] + y[:,None] * base_y_color[None,:]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, c=color)
plt.show()
```

[image]