# GLSL: How to calculate fragments output RGB value based on Photoshops curve value?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I am working on image editing using `OPENGL` in Android and I have applied filter to an image using photoshop curve now I want to reproduce the same in Android using `glsl`. Is there any formula to calculate single fragment color using photoshops curve output value?

**EDIT**

The math behind the photoshop curve has already been answered in this question
[How to recreate the math behind photoshop curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356788/how-to-recreate-the-math-behind-photoshop-curves)  but I am not very clear about how to reproduce the same in `glsl fragment shader`.

Screen Shot of my photoshop curve
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recreate the math behind photoshop curves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356788/how-to-recreate-the-math-behind-photoshop-curves)

Comment: @jozxyqk I have gone through it already but that is not very clear so I posted this question.

Comment: In that case, could you narrow down exactly what you question is in relation to [the linked question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356788/how-to-recreate-the-math-behind-photoshop-curves)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after a function `fragColour = curves(inColour, constants...)`. If you have just the one curve for red, green and blue you apply the same curve to each individually. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5561288/1888983) has a link (below) to code which plots points along the function. The key line is:

```
double y = ...
```

Which you'd return from `curves`. The variable `x` in the loop is your `inColour`. All you need now is the constants which come from the `points` and the second derivative `sd` arrays. These you'll have to pass in as [uniforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099979/glsl-c-arrays-of-uniforms). The function first has to figure out which point each colour `x` is between (finding `cur`, `next`, `sd[i]` and `sd[i+1]`), then evaluate and return `y`.

***EDIT:***
If you just want to apply some curve you've created in photoshop then the problem is much simpler. The easiest way is to create a simple function that gives a similar shape. I use [these](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~pknowles/graphs.html) as a starting point. A [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) curve is also quite common.

This is overkill, but if you do need a more exact result, you could create an image with a linear ramp (e.g. 255 pixels from black to white), apply your filter to it in photoshop and the result becomes a lookup table. Passing in all 255 values to a shader is expensive so if it's a smooth curve you could try some curve fitting tools ([for example](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=online+polynomial+fitting)).

Once you have a function, simply apply it to your colour in GLSL. Applying a gamma curve for example is done [like this](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch24.html):

```
fragColour = vec4(pow(inColour.rgb, 1.0 / gamma.rgb), inColour.a);
```

***EDIT2:***

The curve you have looks very similar to this:

```
fragColour = vec4(pow(inColour.rgb, 1.0 / vec3(0.6)), inColour.a);
```

Or even simpler:

```
fragColour = vec4(inColour.rgb * inColour.rgb, inColour.a);
```

---

Just in case [the link](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d331608-3/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/image-interpolation-spline-cubique/#post3513925) dies, I'll copy the code here (not that I've tested it):

```
Point[] points = /* liste de points, triés par "x" croissants */

double[] sd = secondDerivative(points);

for(int i=0;i<points.length-1;i++) {
    Point cur   = points[i];
        Point next  = points[i+1];

        for(int x=cur.x;x<next.x;x++) {
        double t = (double)(x-cur.x)/(next.x-cur.x);

        double a = 1-t;
        double b = t;
        double h = next.x-cur.x;

        double y= a*cur.y + b*next.y + (h*h/6)*( (a*a*a-a)*sd[i]+ (b*b*b-b)*sd[i+1] );

        draw(x,y); /* ou tout autre utilisation */
    }
}
```

And the second derivative:

```
public static double[] secondDerivative(Point... P) {
    int n = P.length;
    double yp1=0.0; 
    double ypn=0.0;

    // build the tridiagonal system 
    // (assume 0 boundary conditions: y2[0]=y2[-1]=0) 
    double[][] matrix = new double[n][3];
    double[] result = new double[n];
    matrix[0][1]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++) {
        matrix[i][0]=(double)(P[i].x-P[i-1].x)/6;
        matrix[i][1]=(double)(P[i+1].x-P[i-1].x)/3;
        matrix[i][2]=(double)(P[i+1].x-P[i].x)/6;
        result[i]=(double)(P[i+1].y-P[i].y)/(P[i+1].x-P[i].x) - (double)(P[i].y-P[i-1].y)/(P[i].x-P[i-1].x);
    }
    matrix[n-1][1]=1;

    // solving pass1 (up->down)
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
        double k = matrix[i][0]/matrix[i-1][1];
        matrix[i][1] -= k*matrix[i-1][2];
        matrix[i][0] = 0;
        result[i] -= k*result[i-1];
    }
    // solving pass2 (down->up)
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--) {
        double k = matrix[i][2]/matrix[i+1][1];
        matrix[i][1] -= k*matrix[i+1][0];
        matrix[i][2] = 0;
        result[i] -= k*result[i+1];
    }

    // return second derivative value for each point P
    double[] y2 = new double[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) y2[i]=result[i]/matrix[i][1];
    return y2;
}
```

Comment: where is the `curves()` function?

Comment: @Praveen The function you'll be creating. It's essentially `y=f(x)` given `points` and `sd` in the linked code.

Comment: Still confused. Can you please tell me what is `draw(x,y)` and  `constants...`

Comment: @Praveen The linked code generates `x` coordinates and plots points on the curve using draw `draw()`. You have `x`  and want `y`. Easy. use the line `y = ...`  and provide your own `x`. However, there's other stuff on that line you need. Those are the `constants` I referred to. The constants define the shape of the curve and ultimately come from the plot points you've specified just like in photoshop when you click on the graph.

Comment: In the answer you said `x` is  `inColor` but here you are saying `x` is coordinate :-(

Comment: The linked code uses `x` and `y` as the coordinates to `draw()` because it's plotting the points. Instead, you want to find the `y` coordinate on the curve given your `x` coordinate. You're applying the curve function to colour. `x` and `y` in your case are `inColour` and `fragColour` respectively.

Comment: Oh God feeling like shooting myself.. I  am  still not able to understand. I am not getting how to write my `curves` function. What are the `points` and what are the values I should get it from photoshop?

Comment: `points` are the control points you'd use to create the curve. I assumed you wanted to implement the curve editing GUI yourself. I'm not sure if you can get the exact values from photoshop but if you're after a static function things become much easier. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: I am not all implementing GUI... My intension is just take the values for the filter I created from the photoshop and directly apply it to the image using `glsl` thats it..

Comment: @Praveen if you have a screenshot of the curve (add it to your question), I may be able to suggest a function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added screenshot of my photoshop curve to the question.

Comment: Two more doubts.. `inColor` is just the color of original image  right?  and how could you write the function so fast just looking at the curve? any tricks?

Comment: Yes, could just be `fragColour.rgb *= fragColour.rgb`. I'm pretty familiar with maths and what cartesian functions look like. But I also wrote [this](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~pknowles/graphs.html) for just these situations.